# Get a Http Header - Nodejs - Serverless - Aws - Lambda

Tags: node.js, http-headers

The Get Rest API gets a Json output.

How can I get a header output?

1. This code gets the Json output

   ```
   const lambdaHandler = async function lambdaHandler(event, context) {

   const message = "Hello Hugo";
   return {
       statusCode: 200,
       body: JSON.stringify({
       message,    
       }),
     };
   };

   module.exports = {
   lambdaHandler
   };

   const hugo = require('./get-message-to-end-point-helper.js')


   module.exports.getMessage = async (event, context) => 
   hugo.lambdaHandler(event, context);
   ```
2. This is what I was trying to do to get a Http Header

   ```
   const lambdaHandler = async function lambdaHandler(event, context) {

   const response = {
       statusCode: 200,
       headers: {
           'Content-Type':  'text/html'
           },
       body : (<h1> hello hugo </h1>),
   };
   return response;
   };

   const hugo = require('./get-message-to-end-point-helper.js')

   module.exports.getMessage = async (event, context) => hugo.lambdaHandler(event, context);
   ```

For code at part 1:

Expected: {"message":"Hello Hugo"}
Result: {"message":"Hello Hugo"}

For code at part 2:

Expected: hello hugo

Result {"message": "Internal server error"}

The Error from the test:

```
Tue Jul 23 23:11:08 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"message\":\"Hello hugo\"}"}
Tue Jul 23 23:11:08 UTC 2019 : Method response body after transformations: {"message":"Hello hugo"}
Tue Jul 23 23:11:08 UTC 2019 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5d37940c-e41a72f3254e54ad9a47ecb9;Sampled=0}
Tue Jul 23 23:11:08 UTC 2019 : Successfully completed execution
Tue Jul 23 23:11:08 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is the second block of code. I was missing the quotes around the  hello hugo .

```
const lambdaHandler = async function lambdaHandler(event, context) {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':  'text/html'
            },
        body : '<h1> hello hugo </h1><p>go Serverless </p>',
    };
    return response;
};
```